# fade different divs in and out along with input text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, input

I am fairly new to jQuery, and am trying to reproduce the help bubbles from this site http://www.wolframalpha.com/

I have made some progress, but am now struggling.
This is what i have so far:

html of the help bubbles:

```
<div class="help" id="help1">
  <p>foo</p>
</div>

<div class="help" id="help2">
  <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

with the style:

```
div.help {
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #gray;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery which gets run when dom is loaded:

```
function help() {
  $('#help1').delay(1000).fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#help2').fadeIn(500);
  });    
}
```

This fades the first bubble in after a short delay, and then fades it out, then follows with the second bubble.

What i would like to do now is have some corresponding text in an input fade in and out along with the bubbles (as in the example i linked to). I don't really know how to tackle this..

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note that might put you down the correct path is that the 'text' you are seeing supposedly being in the input box, is actually a div stacked on top of the input box, creating the illusion that it is in the input box.

Also, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/javascript/index.html.js) might help also. ;)